# How can I request a package for "authselect" on Ubuntu?

Tags: packaging, pam, sssd

I find [authselect](https://github.com/pbrezina/authselect) (link to project on GitHub) a very convenient piece of software. How can I request that it be packaged for Ubuntu?

Comment: Unable to locate three of authselect package's dependencies.

Comment: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Comment: @karel On Ubuntu, `pkgconfig` is `pkg-config`, I think that `popt-devel` is `libpopt-dev` and you might be able to get by with `autotools-dev` instead of `gettext-dev`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to go through official channels to request a package. The Ubuntu Wiki [describes how to request a new package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages) for Ubuntu.

The process seems quite easy! Just file a bug on Launchpad and tag your bug with `needs-packaging`. Then you can fill out the bug description with the same information you added to this AskUbuntu question (but don't forget to mention what license it's under).

Comment: It's even better when community members volunteer to become packagers and package maintainers. There are over 1900 "needs-packaging" requests queued, and very few volunteers working that list. Debian has a chronic shortage of volunteer package maintainers. If a piece of software is truly valuable to you, spend an afternoon learning how to package it so everybody benefits.